# set print option on printing a document

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

I want to set my settings on my print job.
For example I want to print 4 pages of a pdf file on 1 A4 paper.
How can I do it?

This is my code to print pdf files:

```
    private void SendToPrinter()
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
            info.Verb = "print";
            info.FileName = ofd.FileName;
            info.CreateNoWindow = true;
            info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo = info;
            p.Start();

            p.WaitForInputIdle();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            if (false == p.CloseMainWindow())
                p.Kill();
        }
    }
```

Comment: cant you set the settings directly before printing through code? Or do you have a need to change settings based on some criteria?

Comment: you seem to be starting a separate process for printing. In that case the code in which you code runs becomes a separate process and hence dont think there will be easy ways unless there are commandline parameters

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it using `info.Verb = "print"`. By setting the `Verb` as `print` you are basically using the windows shell command `print` which takes two arguments, Filename and Printer device name.

If you want to print pdf files with specific print settings you have to use a third party software (like Ghostscript) which could print pdfs with command line arguments. See [this](http://www.torres.at/pdf-printing-net/) article for more information.